# selectableItemBackground color change for pre-lollipop versions

Tags: android, ripple

For Lollipop, ripple color can simply be modified using `colorControlHighlight`. But for pre-Lollipop (< API21), how can I change the color of pressed state achieved by setting the background to `?attr/selectableItemBackground`

Comment: you can use a selector

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: this is now possible using AppCompat and [backgroundTint](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/appcompat/R.attr.html#backgroundTint)

```
   backgroundTint="@color/yourColor"
```

Previous solution:

Not sure this is what you want but I ended up doing this programmatically:

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        ColorStateList colors = new ColorStateList(new int[][]{
                new int[]{android.R.attr.state_enabled},
        }, new int[]{pressed});
        GradientDrawable item = new GradientDrawable();
        item.setCornerRadius(radius);
        item.setColor(normal);
        RippleDrawable ripple = new RippleDrawable(colors, item, null);
        button.setBackgroundDrawable(ripple);
    } else {
        StateListDrawable stateListDrawable = new StateListDrawable();
        GradientDrawable item;
        item = new GradientDrawable();
        item.setCornerRadius(radius);
        item.setColor(pressed);
        stateListDrawable.addState(new int[]{android.R.attr.state_enabled, android.R.attr.state_pressed}, item);
        item = new GradientDrawable();
        item.setCornerRadius(radius);
        item.setColor(normal);
        stateListDrawable.addState(new int[]{android.R.attr.state_enabled}, item);
        button.setBackgroundDrawable(stateListDrawable);
    }
```

Comment: `android:backgroundTint` requires API >=21. If you need to support the older versions use just `backgroundTint` property (without `android` prefix). I have tested this on the device with API 15.

Comment: Thanks, updating the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use this:

```
<item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/yourColor</item>
```